# Detecting and acting on scroll to bottom of page event

Tags: javascript, html, css, dhtml

http://dabbler.org/home/asdf/scrolling/test.html

Does anyone see anything wrong with this code?

I can't figure out what is wrong with it, but my intentions are such that when the user hits the bottom of the page, the page scrolls to the top.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed a closing parenthesis:

```
function getheight() {
    var myWidth = 0,
        myHeight = 0;
    if (typeof (window.innerWidth) == 'number') {
        //Non-IE
        myWidth = window.innerWidth;
        myHeight = window.innerHeight;
    } else if (document.documentElement && (document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.documentElement.clientHeight)) {
        //IE 6+ in 'standards compliant mode'
        myWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
        myHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    } else if (document.body && (document.body.clientWidth || document.body.clientHeight)) {
        //IE 4 compatible
        myWidth = document.body.clientWidth;
        myHeight = document.body.clientHeight;
    }
    var scrolledtonum = window.pageYOffset + myHeight - 16;
    var heightofbody = document.body.offsetHeight;
    if (scrolledtonum = heightofbody) {
        alert('asdf!')
    }

//???? } <--
```

Here is a working version with some code fixes: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/8zhmg/

Comment: Thanks a ton. (Need an extra character...)

Answer (score 0):

On your last line you have

```
if (scrolledtonum = heightofbody)
```

That should be

```
if (scrolledtonum == heightofbody)
```

Not sure if that'll be the problem though

Answer (score 0):

Your missing a closing tag on your function! (at the very end!)

Argh.. @Neal beat me to it!

Comment: ...yes. and that is **not** my name